# $(g,k)$ modules for $\mathrm{SU}(1,1)$

Tags: group-theory

Let the group be $\mathrm{SU}(1,1)$, choose maximal compact subgroup 
$$
K_{\mathbb{R}}=\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
e^{i\theta} & 0\\
0 & e^{i\theta}
\end{array}\right),\,\theta\in \mathbb{R}\right\} \simeq \mathrm{SO}(2)\simeq \mathrm{U}(1),
$$
and let $g = \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$. Why is it that for any $(g,K)$-module $V$, all eigenvalues of 
$$
H=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$
are integers. Here  $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is the usual set of $2$ by $2$ with trace $0$.

Comment: Please check that the notation is still correct after my edit.